# loop0 is empty, why seeing blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 0

Tags: kernel, disk

I didn't setup `loop0`, there is no device there.

When doing `fdisk -l /dev/loop0`, I can see:

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I think this means no device mount to `loop0`

but I see this log in dmesg:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 0
```

Comment: Is this all there is about *loop0* in the logs? Try  as sudo *cd /var/log; grep -nriIl loop0*. My system returns nothing here.

Comment: Maybe something was using loop0 (or trying to use it) earlier (for example that something was loop mounted during boot).

Comment: `losetup -a` returns nothing.